# Replace jquery text with TM character entity, with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, character-encoding

How do I change text with TM character entity in the text, with jquery?

For example :

TM = &#8482 ; ™

```
<h1>Some text&#8482;</h1>
```

Now I want to change text on button click to 'This is some other text™'

```
$('#click1').on('touchend', function () {
    $('h1').text("This is some other text");
});
```

How can I place the ™ with jquery and how can I place it in `<sup></sup>`?

Comment: have you tried using `String.prototype.replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('h1').html("This is some other text <sup>&#8482;</sup>");
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/diqego/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html` instead of `.text`:

```
$('h1').html('This is some other text &#8482;');
```